# Limit of $\lim_{x\to\infty} (1+\frac{f(x)}{x})^x$ for $f(x) = o(x)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

I am well aware of the theorem which states that $\lim_{x\to\infty} (1+\frac{r}{x})^x = e^r$ for a constant $r$, however I am faced with with the question of if $f(x)= o(x)$ (*using little o notation*) what is the limit $\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+\frac{f(x)}{x})^x$?

This winds up in the indeterminate form $(1+0)^\infty$.

I expect but am having trouble proving that this limit becomes $\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+\frac{f(x)}{x})^x = \lim_{x\to\infty} (e^{f(x)})$ which might or might not simplify further based on $f$.

If the question is too general and too dependent on the nature of $f$, then for a specific case consider $f = -\frac{1}{2} \ln x$ which I expect $\lim_{x\to\infty}(1-\frac{\ln x}{2x})^x = \lim_{x\to\infty} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\ln x} = \lim_{x\to\infty} x^{-\frac{1}{2}} = 0$

Plugging in test values seems to support my claim, however of course proof by example is invalid.

Comment: First of all, $f(x)=1=o(x)$ and $f(x)=2=o(x)$. So that's not enough information to determine the limit. Finally, if $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ then the limit is infinity.

Comment: For $f(x) = 1$ it is well known that it becomes $e^1 = e^{f(x)}$ and for $g(x) = 2$ it is well known that it becomes $e^2 = e^{g(x)}$.  I ask not for the left side of the identity, but ask to confirm if for general $f$ that it becomes $\lim e^{f(x)}$

Comment: How can it become $e^{f(x)}$? The limit doesn't have any "unbound" $x$, so it can only be a constant, not a function of $x$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: OP is saying the limit should be $\lim_{x \to \infty}e^{f(x)}$ and not $e^{f(x)}$. And he is correct as shown in my answer.

Comment: Exactly.  In the case of $f(x)=\sqrt{x}$ you would have $\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{\sqrt{x}} = \infty$ and in the case of $g(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ you have $\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{\frac{1}{x}} = e^0 = 1$, both well known examples.  I was curious of a more general form.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is best to go via logs. Let $L$ be the desired limit. Then $$\begin{aligned}\log L &= \log\left\{\lim_{x \to \infty}\left(1 + \frac{f(x)}{x}\right)^{x}\right\}\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}\log\left(1 + \frac{f(x)}{x}\right)^{x}\text{ (by continuity of }\log)\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}x\log\left(1 + \frac{f(x)}{x}\right)\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}x\cdot\frac{f(x)}{x}\cdot\dfrac{\log\left(1 + \dfrac{f(x)}{x}\right)}{\dfrac{f(x)}{x}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)\cdot\lim_{x \to \infty}\dfrac{\log\left(1 + \dfrac{f(x)}{x}\right)}{\dfrac{f(x)}{x}}\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)\cdot\lim_{y \to 0}\frac{\log(1 + y)}{y}\text{ (by putting }y = f(x)/x)\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}f(x)\end{aligned}$$ It follows that the desired limit exists only when $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}f(x) = A$ exists and then the desired limit is $L = e^{A}$.

**Update**: Readers may have failed to notice a minor but subtle error which I spotted just now. The step where I try to multiply and divide by $f(x)/x$ is invalid when $f(x)=0$ for infinitely many large values of $x$ without any bound. In this case also the result holds good, but needs more analysis. If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$ exists then it must be $0$ and in this case the proof can be easily completed by showing that $\log L=0$ so that $L=1$ (a good example of such a function is $f(x)=(\sin\pi x)/x$). In case $f(x)$ does not tend to a limit when $x\to\infty$, then it can be seen that the limit corresponding to $\log L$ does not exist and hence $L$ does not exist (an example of this case would be $f(x)=\sqrt{x}\sin\pi x$).

Comment: That was a good catch about the limit of $f$ not being guaranteed to exist and not necessarily being differentiable, I could have been more careful with my wording of the question but I was hoping to avoid needing those conditions for an answer.

Comment: It seems i skiped some thing! how $lim_{x tends to 0}f(x)/x=0?$ ?

Comment: @Idris: When we say that $f(x)=o(x)$ when $x\to\infty$ then it means that $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty}f(x)/x =0$.

Comment: I did not see it, thanks

Comment: In general, *little-o notation* means if $f(x) = o(g(x))$ then $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 0$

Comment: @Singh, I am not convinced by your word ''only'' in your conclusion. If you remove it, the conclusion is ok for me. But with that word, ....

Comment: @singh, we can say that lim (f*g)=limf *lim g if we know previously that both limits exist and we do not have indeterminate form. So, if lim f(x) do not exists for example, you cannot arrive to the end, becaus eyou stoped at the moment you use lim(fg)=limf*limg

Comment: @Idris: What I mean by "only" is that if $A$ exists or is $-\infty$ then $L$ exists and in all other cases $L$ does not exist.

Comment: for me: the condition limf(x)=A is a sufficient condition and not necessary (at least your proof do not include it)

Comment: @Idris: it is necessary. If $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$ and $\lim g(x)$ exists and is non-zero then limiting behavior of $h(x)$ is same as that of $f(x)$.

Comment: Now i am convinced by the necessity and i am writing it, i will post it in a moment.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y = \left(1+\dfrac{f(x)}x\right)^x$. We then have
$$z=\ln(y) = x \ln \left(1+\dfrac{f(x)}x\right) = \dfrac{\ln \left(1+\dfrac{f(x)}x\right)}{1/x}$$
Since $f(x) - o(x)$, we can use L'Hospital to see what we get
$$\dfrac{\dfrac1{1+\dfrac{f(x)}x}\left(\dfrac{xf'(x)-f(x)}{x^2}\right)}{-1/x^2} = \dfrac{f(x)-xf'(x)}{1+\dfrac{f(x)}x}$$
Since you have your $f(x) = o(x)$, we have
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \dfrac{\ln \left(1+\dfrac{f(x)}x\right)}{1/x} = \lim_{x \to \infty}(f(x)-xf'(x))$$
Hence, if $f(x) = o(x)$, we have
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \left(1+\dfrac{f(x)}x\right)^x = \exp\left( \lim_{x \to \infty}(f(x)-xf'(x)) \right)$$

Comment: Your answer assumes too much (e.g. that $f$ is differentiable).

Answer (score 1):

I cannot attach a file in a comment, i post it as a new answer, but it is not one![image: necessity]

Comment: Good, this is exactly what you need to understand when dealing with product rule of limits. If one of limits is non zero then limit of product has same behavior as that of the other factor.

Comment: You shouldn't need an image for this - all of this is writeable in MathJax.

Comment: By the way you should learn $\mathrm\LaTeX$. It is not that difficult.

Comment: i know latex, and i have used it in some of my earlier contributions in this forum, but it takes much time